# Can't use Splice with Array from String slice

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to re-array the stored string in a google script cache which involves using splice,

Code is basically

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var arr = str.slice(",");
var rem = arr.splice(2,1);
```

But this gives an error "tmpArr.splice is not a function" and I don't understand why. I can console.log elements in the array with `Logger.log(tmpArr[2])` so it must be one? Right?
:-s

Thanks for any help

Comment: It's mainly because you are working with an `string`...you need a way to convert it into an array, like `var arr = str.split(',');`...that way you can use slice or splice on your `arr` variable.

Comment: `so it must be one? Right?` for future reference, you are probably better of NOT assuming. You can check what is the real type of a value using the `typeof` operator, so you can do `console.log(typeof tmpArr)` and you'd get `"string"` if it was a string or `"object"` if it was an array...or any other object. But it's at least a good first check. To see if it's actually an array, you can try `Array.isArray(tmpArr)` which returns a boolean. A word of warning `typeof null` also reports `"object"`.

Comment: yep it should be arr. thanks @vlaz thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `arr` is a string. `arr[2]` is taking the 3rd char of the string.

[`.splice` is Array.prototype method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), so you need to work with array. 
If you want to convert a string to array use for instance [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: @vlaz thanks for the edit. Will include links next time ;)

Comment: No worries. Your answer wasn't really bad without them but it's always easier to click and find out more info.

Comment: Aargh. Got my splits and slices back to front. Thanks papi

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use `split` instead of `slice`.

```js
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var arr = str.split(","); //Use split() instead of slice()
var rem = arr.splice(2,1);
console.log(rem);
```